# Perl SOAP::Lite Create request from provided schema and WSDL

Tags: xml, perl, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm given various schemas and the odd wsdl document as well describing an API of a new product I'm about to use, it is rather underdocumented as always and I'm getting fairly frustrated with the limited toy examples in the SOAP::Lite documentation.

How can I create a client and list possible methods I can use off the wsdl and schemas provided?

Comment: http://www.soapui.org/ makes good wsdl based clients/envelopes. `soap::lite` was great module perhaps ten years ago.

Comment: I was introduced to said product with soapUI I dont see how I can use that with the software I'm asked to produce now though. Copy and paste XML and use my own placeholders as the values for parameters? That's horrendous the whole SOAP::Lite deal was so that I can write everything without reading or writing a line of raw xml myself..

Comment: Perhaps by inheriting base class somewhere and giving prepared envelope to the parent. I would be interested in other options too.

Comment: What about other (more modern) packages and languages for this kind of thing? Perhaps excluding Java

Comment: Well I could try something with XML::Compile, IF I could install it. Topic for another question..

Comment: http://weblog.bulknews.net/post/58079418600/plenv-alternative-for-perlbrew if you want to install newer perl into your home dir.

Comment: No I sorted it out I was missing plenty of headers (many an answer around), cheers though another alternative to know about!

Comment: In any way, don't forget to come back if you succeed in building client out of wsdl. `:)`

Comment: Pft good luck with that.. I don't think I'd have gone past the complex types. I could read in the ready envelopes and write my own setters off a XML::Compile template result, job security for life.